# Creating a copy of a List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to store two variables and then check if they have not changed.

```
List<CatalogInfo> list_catalogs = new List<CatalogInfo>();
List<FileInfo> list_files = new List<FileInfo>(); 
List<CatalogInfo> list_catalogs_for_check_changed = new List<CatalogInfo>();
List<FileInfo> list_files_check_changed = new List<FileInfo>();
```

When I do:

```
list_catalogs_for_check_changed = list_catalogs;
list_files_check_changed = list_files;
```

But When I add to list_catalogs or list_files Items I see in debager that Items add to list_catalogs_for_check_changed or  list_files_check_changed. Why??? I don't add Items to with variables.

```
  list_catalogs.Add(new CatalogInfo() { Action = "Create", Path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath });
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference betweeen Value types and Reference types. http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deep cloning objects in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HenkHolterman That question has a similar answer but is not at all the same question.

Comment: It is close enough and since this question has a totally nondescript title it's not worth keeping open.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I disagree - "why doesn't this work" and "how do I achieve this" are completely different; plus, there is no need to implement any custom cloning just to copy a list, so the answers to the other question are completely inappropriate. If the title is "nondescript," maybe edit it? Closing a question as a duplicate because of a bad title is a total non-sequitur.

Answer (score 6):

When you do this:

```
list_catalogs_for_check_changed = list_catalogs;
```

You are not making a copy of the list, you are assigning a new *reference* to the same list. If you want to create a new list with the same items, do this:

```
    list_catalogs_for_check_changed = new List<CatalogInfo>(list_catalogs);
```

This assigns a new `List<CatalogInfo>` and passes the list from which to copy the elements, resulting in two independent lists with the same items.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't add Items to with variables.

Indeed, you don't. You are adding items to the **lists**. If you do (from the question):

```
list_catalogs_for_check_changed = list_catalogs;
list_files_check_changed = list_files;
```

Then both `list_catalogs_for_check_changed` and  `list_catalogs` hold a reference to the **same** list of `CatalogInfo`. Likewise, `list_files` and `list_files_check_changed` hold a reference to the **same** list of `FileInfo`s. It therefore follows that if you add an item to that list, it will be visible via either variable.

The variable is not the list: the list is somewhere on the managed heap. The variable is just the **reference** to the list. Assigning one list variable to another copies the **reference**. It does ***not*** make a copy of the *list*.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
list_catalogs_for_check_changed = list_catalogs;
```

You are handing over a `reference` to list_catalogs. You want to copy it.

[This is an article describing value types vs reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)